# Power Management software for Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, power-management

I am using ubuntu on Virtual Harddisk. THe problem is when ever I use ubuntu on my laptop, the laptop goes crazy, Screen Brigtness is high and I can't lower it, Processor usage is 100% and Laptop heats up like a coal. And fans also go crazy. I want a software that would help me do power management for achieving long battery life by reducing power usage by Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: There is small possibility that your ubuntu has a bug. Try to update your ubunt as it is old.

Comment: I understand you are running it as a guest os so you have to check if the virtualizing software is working as it should be. Please specify which software you are using to achieve virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing powertop to check what's sucking you CPU time, but you'll want to read something about it to know what to look for. The graphics card is the other big power drain, so you may want to share what hardware you have and what drivers you use.